# Terminate called without an active exception (throw in catch all expression)

Tags: c++, exception

I have a code block like this:

```
namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

struct Container {
    struct Item {
        bi::set_member_hook<> link;
        int x;
    };

    struct Cmp {
        bool opeartor()(Item const& it1, Item const &it2) const {
            return it1.x < it2.x;
        }
    };
    using Set = typename bi::set<Item,
                            bi::member_hook<Item, bi::set_member_hook<>, &Item::link>,
                            bi::compare<Cmp>,
                            bi::constant_time_size<false>
                            >;



    Container(Container const& o) {
        auto cloner = [](const Item &x) {
            return current_allocator().construct<Item>(x);
        };

        with_allocator(_alloctor, [&] {
            new (&_data) Set;

            _data.clone_from(o._data, cloner, current_deleter<Item>());
        }
    }


private:
    Set _data;
};
```

The program sometime terminated with this message:

> terminate called without an active exception

I found an answer from stackoverflow that because of `throw` was called without an active exception. But if without an active exception, then it can not reach the `catch` block.

I'm sorry for my bad English

EDIT: The code example was updated.

EDIT 2: Correct the code as @:RemyLebeau recommended, and the bug still happen.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are throwing the initial exception. And FYI, this code won't compile since `ptr` is not in scope inside the `catch` block to pass to `free_memory()`.  In this example, `allocate_memory()` should be above the `try` block, there is no point in calling `free_memory()` if `allocate_memory()` fails: `complex_struct *ptr = allocate_memory(); try { clone(ptr, other); } catch(...) { free_memory(ptr); throw; }`

Comment: Why are you declaring a non-pointer `Set` member and then calling `placement-new` on it for the same type? That is completely wrong, and totally unnecessary. Get rid of the `new`, as the `_data` member is already fully constructed by the compiler before your constructor's body is entered. And as such, you don't need to call the member'd destructor manually if your constructor throws, the compiler will handle that for you, so get rid of your `try/catch`, too. And remove your `noexcept` specifier, since your constructor can clearly throw an exception

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm sorry, I used a custom allocator, and did not put the code here. I want items will be allocated using `_allocator`. The function `with_allocator` impl RAII idiom, then the function `current_allocator()` will return exactly `_allocator`.

Comment: `Container(Container const& o) { auto cloner = ...; _data.clone_from(o._data, cloner, current_deleter<Item>()); }` That is all your copy constructor needs. Assuming simply `Container(Container const& o) : _data(o._data) {}` or even just `Container(Container const& o) = default;` is not sufficient to copy a `bi::set` to another (I don't use boost)

Comment: Whether you use a custom allocator or not, calling `placement-new` on a previously constructed object is still wrong. `Set _data;` is a fully constructed object, so `new (&_data) Set;` risks leaking or even corrupting memory. If you want to use `placement-new`, you need to change `_data` to `char _data[sizeof(Set)]` or equivalent instead, and then save and use the `Set*` pointer that `placement-new` returns so you can access the `Set` object correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message

> terminate called without an active exception

actually takes to mean

> terminate called without an active C++ exception

`terminate()` may be called for many different reasons, not limited to unhandled C++ exceptions. The `catch (...)` clause only catches C++ exceptions. In your particular case, `terminate()` may be called within `allocate_memory()` or `clone()` directly, or by runtime due to unhandled non-C++ exceptions (like some low-level Windows exceptions that should be captured with [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/structured-exception-handling)). In either case, the catch block is never entered.

Comment: I used a framework which print backtrace when program was terminated. The last function in the reported call stack is this function. the `clone()` function used in my function is `boost::intrusive::set::clone_from` (I can not copy and pasted the code here because of security reason). I don't think that the compiler inline this function, then it should show up in the call stack if there is an exception.